# 【Django】外部ファイルに定義した変数をforms.pyで読み込みたい

Tags: python, django

djangoでModelFormを利用しないFormの中でSelectを定義しているのですが、この選択肢一覧をstaticに配置し、これを読み込みたいのですが、方法がわかりません

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
import os

class sampleForm(forms.Form):
    pref_id = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=PREF_CHOICE)
```

上記のフォームで以下の外部ファイルで定義した変数(PREF_CHOICE)を読み込みたいと考えています
なお、外部ファイルはlist.pyとしてstaticフォルダに配置しています

```
PREF_CHOICE = (
    ('', '都道府県'),
    ('1', '北海道'),
    ('2', '青森県'),
    ('3', '岩手県'),
    ('4', '宮城県'),
    ('5', '秋田県'),
    ('6', '山形県'),
    ('7', '福島県'),
    ('8', '茨城県'),
    ('9', '栃木県'),
    ('10', '群馬県'),
    ('11', '埼玉県'),
    ('12', '千葉県'),
    ('13', '東京都'),
    ('14', '神奈川県'),
    ('15', '新潟県'),
    ('16', '富山県'),
    ('17', '石川県'),
    ('18', '福井県'),
    ('19', '山梨県'),
    ('20', '長野県'),
    ('21', '岐阜県'),
    ('22', '静岡県'),
    ('23', '愛知県'),
    ('24', '三重県'),
    ('25', '滋賀県'),
    ('26', '京都府'),
    ('27', '大阪県'),
    ('28', '兵庫県'),
    ('29', '奈良県'),
    ('30', '和歌山県'),
    ('31', '鳥取県'),
    ('32', '島根県'),
    ('33', '岡山県'),
    ('34', '広島県'),
    ('35', '山口県'),
    ('36', '徳島県'),
    ('37', '香川県'),
    ('38', '愛媛県'),
    ('39', '高知県'),
    ('40', '福岡県'),
    ('41', '佐賀県'),
    ('42', '長崎県'),
    ('43', '熊本県'),
    ('44', '大分県'),
    ('45', '宮崎県'),
    ('46', '鹿児島'),
    ('47', '沖縄県'),
)
```

forms.pyの中に書けば、問題なく動きますが、不細工なのでなんとかしたく...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

実装している forms.py と同じディレクトリに(list.pyというモジュール名はちょっと避けた方が良いので) `consts.py` という名前で置いてください。

そして、forms.pyの最初の方で、 `from .consts import PREF_CHOICE` としてimportしてください。

Answer (score 1):

staticフォルダは（Djangoのデフォルト設定では）静的ファイルを配置するフォルダですので、Pythonモジュールを配置する場所として不適切です。

Pythonのパスが通っているディレクトリに配置すれば、適切にimport文を追加することで参照可能になりますが、list.pyという名前はPython標準ライブラリの`list`関数と重複してしまうため、好ましくありません。

list.pyの名前を変更し、forms.pyと同じディレクトリに配置、forms.pyからimportすることをおすすめします。

ファイル構造例

```
{your_django_app}
├── choices.py  <- 元list.py
├── forms.py
├── models.py
└── views.py
```

forms.py例

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django import forms
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
import os

from . import choices
# または from {your_django_appのモジュールパス} import choices

class sampleForm(forms.Form):
    pref_id = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=choices.PREF_CHOICE)
```

なお、使用しているPythonのバージョンが3.0以上であれば、 `from __future__ import absolute_import` は不要です。